# Display output in a separate window in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

At the end of the execution of my program in MATLAB, the results, stored in a variable are being displayed in the command window. How to display the contents of a variable on to a different window?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this method suits your need, but try this: suppose variable x has the processed information.

```
strx = num2str(x);set(handles.textboxname, 'String', strx);
```